# I have made URLs user friendly through htaccess but how to stop google from indexing URLs with file extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

i had an URL like

www.example.com/search.php?category=somename

i changed it to a seo friendly URL

www.example.com/cityname/somename

but google is indexing both the URLs. How can i stop the first URL being indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 301 redirect all your old URLs so that you will not loose PageRank juice from it.

In your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect old URLs

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search.php$ /cityname/%1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite new URLs

RewriteRule ^cityname/([^/]*)$ /search.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Google will now edit old URLs with the new format and you will not loose PageRank.

Comment: I tried this but its changing the URL. The second URL i.e the seo one is changed after using this